# How does SQL Server know which disk cluster is allocated for a specific extent?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, database-administration, sqlstorage

Assume that we have a table with an unique clustered index. We query a row in that table using index key value. SQL Server will use index seek to find related data pages.

But how does SQL Server read those data pages from physical disk after having their file_id:page_id? How does it know the position of disk sector/cluster?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not deal with disk sector/cluster.
It reads from `files` that are logically divided into `pages` (8Kb).
`Extent` is 8 consecutive pages.

Every table has `IAM` page(s) associated with it where all the extents allocated to this table are listed (it's a bitmap page where 1 means extent is allocated to the object an 0 means it is not).

SQL Server maintains internal pointers to the first IAM page and the
first data page of a heap. Those  pointers can be found in the system view `sys.system_internals_allocation_units`.

In case of clustered index all the data lives in pages as usual, and it still can be read using IAM page(s), but it can be also accessed in "ordered" way using `binary tree` that is index.

This means that over the data (index leaf pages) server builds additional searching structure that also consists of pages, the root page directs you to lower index levels in base of clustered index key.

Conclusion: all addresses presented in the index pages consist of `file_id:page_id`, not of cluster/sector.

Here you can find how database structures are organized:

[Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008 T-SQL Querying](https://books.google.it/books?id=FZlCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT332&lpg=PT332&dq=%22The%20structure%20is%20called%20a%20heap%20because%20the%20data%20is%20not%20organized%20in%20any%20order;%20rather%22&source=bl&ots=S6RYRc19Q3&sig=FpxLMmHIdCrwd3nWsZj1ZA1pmTc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9o9vVoIvXAhWE2hoKHVMJC-EQ6AEIKzAB#v=onepage&q=%22The%20structure%20is%20called%20a%20heap%20because%20the%20data%20is%20not%20organized%20in%20any%20order%3B%20rather%22&f=false)

Comment: Thank for your answer. I totally agreed with you that all addresses presented in the index pages consist of file_id:page_id. 
But file_id and page_id are both internally used by SQL OS. The allocation unit of physical disk is sector or cluster. 
A SQL extend or a SQL data page is physically stored in disk sectors or clusters. To read a data page, SQL must know which cluster storing that page.

Comment: Absolutely no, it's OS (Windows) who translates file into clusters/sectors. None of windows apps does it directlly, their internal code always use windows api functions. SQL Server is written in C, not in assembler :)

Comment: Did you ever write a simple program in C that just reads the file? You can read from a certain offset iether, but you NEVER see to what sector it corresponds physically, all that you pass to a corresponding function is file path/name and offset you need to read from

Comment: Based on your answers, in order to read a data page, I think SQL OS will convert its file_id:page_id to a file offset value and then call a Windows API to read data file (mdf, ndf) at that position(offset). Is it right man ? :D

Comment: I don't know exactly if it passes page_id directly or translates it into bytes, but it's the same, because page_id * 8Kb gives you offset in Kbytes

Comment: I do not know how SQL Server does it exactly too. I Just raised this question to try to understand how it does internally :D . Many thanks for your help, man !

Comment: Why don't you ask how Word, Paint and Media Player work with files? All of them read/write files, none of them know anything about sectors/ clusters. Your question is NOT about SQL Server, it's about how Windows APIs are written. I cannot vote from phone to close it, but I'll do it once I'm at work